# PHP array created inside for loop but not printing

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I created a script to get data from a mysql table for every year and put into array of respective year. I checked the sql and the while loop iteration is working.

```
<?php



mysql_select_db($database_hari,$hari);

$start=2013 ;
$end=2015;
$xdata=array();
for($year=$start;$year<=$end;$year++){

     ${"y".$year}=array();
    $i=0;
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT tld_master.location,tld_dose.year, AVG(tld_dose.dose)*4 as avgdose from tld_master left join tld_dose on tld_master.tldno=tld_dose.tldno where tld_master.site='F' and tld_dose.year=$year GROUP BY tld_dose.year, tld_dose.tldno");

    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$xdata[$i]=$result['location'];
 ${"y".$year."[".$i."]"}=$result['avgdose'];


$i++;
}

    }
print_r($y2015);

?>
```

Print displays "Array()"
But if I am echoing each array value inside for loop it prints. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Have you tried with `${"y".$year}[$i]` instead of `${"y".$year."[".$i."]"}`?

Comment: This is really weird what you are doing though, dynamically creating variable names. You can just use `$years = []` and then `$years[$year][$i] = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
${"y".$year} = array()
```

creates a variable named `$y2015`, holding an array.  The code

```
${"y".$year."[".$i."]"} = ...
```

creates an oddly named variable `$y2015[0]`, which is completely unrelated to the variable `$y2015`.  You want:

```
${"y".$year}[$i] = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are ways to solve your problem with variable variables, I suggest you take different approach. What if year is a value you do not expect? It can easily lead to confusion. Instead you can use an array that you can iterate through without knowing the exact value of the year.

```
$yearArray = array();
for($year=$start;$year<=$end;$year++){
    $sql = "SELECT
              tld_master.location,tld_dose.year, AVG(tld_dose.dose)*4 as avgdose 
            FROM tld_master 
            LEFT JOIN tld_dose on tld_master.tldno=tld_dose.tldno 
            WHERE tld_master.site='F' and tld_dose.year={$year} 
            GROUP BY tld_dose.year, tld_dose.tldno";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $yearArray[$year] = array();
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $xdata[] = $result['location'];
        $yearArray[$year][] = $result['avgdose'];
    }
}
```

Now you can print the `$yearArray` variable to see your actual results. And you can use it easily.

```
print_r($yearArray["2015"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You override your array value with this statement `${"y".$year."[".$i."]"}=$result['avgdose'];` Try to use this one instead: `${"y".$year."[".$i."]"}[]=$result['avgdose'];`

Comment: Thank you.I changed like this  ${"y".$year}[$i]=$result['avgdose']; and working